Does Digital multimeter need any AL program?
Unlike analog type, Digital Multimeters (DMMs) convert the external qunatities into Digital output and displays on small LCD. Does this work only on circuits or it uses any microcontroller (which use any kind of assembly language) to give output?

you might  try: https://sigrok.org/wiki/Multimeter_ICs

Why would you focus on the language used to program the MCU (if present)? Some DMMs use a separate analog front end and MCU, but in this day of 10-cent 32-bit MCUs there's no necessity of using assembly language. For an 8-bit MCU such as an 8051 derivative (which are still used in new designs) it still might be desirable. Early ones were based on the Intersil ICL7106, which has quite good performance for 3.5 digits, no MCU, just a single CMOS chip with logic and analog sections and static LCD driver.

As Transistor points out, most multimeters use an ASIC that runs no reprogrammable software at all.
If you build a lower-volume product with specific features that market-available ASICs don't offer, then well, you might use or add a microcontroller.
I, however, see absolutely no compelling reason that microcontroller would then be programmed in assembly language: By the special-use case nature of the device, you're probably already putting it in a market segment where using the smallest possible microcontroller makes less sense than using one with built-in LCD controller,

enough IO pins to connect to ADCs and so on. And such microcontrollers are typically just programmed in a machine-independent language (mostly, C). There's absolutely nothing to be gained by programming your communication port to the ADC, or your LCD interface, in assembly: your compiler produces machine code that is probably faster than hand-assembled constructs, and the old "but with assembler I can count instructions and thus cycles and thus can do tight timing loops" doesn't apply to these kinds of chips, often with variable-latency DRAM, at all.

@SpehroPefhany, I did a bit of 8052 development, and I don't recall ever writing a single assembly language statement. (Maybe that's a benefit of choosing Keil.)

@SolomonSlow I wrote a bunch of stuff in .asm for the 80C49, which was then ported to some 8051 variants. It would have been a lot more work to try to write it in C without support for fractional arithmetic, which I used (a 4-level stack and 32-bit fractional numbers) to do control algorithms and polynomial evaluation. Now you can just throw double-precision floating point at it (single precision was not good enough due to the matrix condition numbers), at a substantial cost in speed and power. For just dealing with characters and such like, C is good enough.

Once you have the assembly routines written for the math and other functions, it's not much different either way- you're either doing trivial stuff or calling a subroutine in .asm or a function in C.  C is a pretty low-level language. Definitely Keil is the best there is for 8051, most of the open-source stuff uses SDCC which I was not impressed with at all (maybe it's gotten better).

DMMs can be built entirely in hardware without software or firmware. The ICL1706/1707, for example, was a popular choice for at least forty years.

The 7106 (for LCD) and 7107 (for LED) were basically an analog to digital converter (ADC) with some logic to drive the display.
The datasheet is worth a read.

Well I see this IC set works without any need of external circuit to display.

It depends on implementation, but usually at least big producers have ASIC that is used for the measurement part and there is usually then a micro that controls the screen, buttons etc. But i've seen also complete ASIC implementation.
